# Update DocValues: Store "clicks" of a document in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

Today I read the [announcement of Apache Lucene and Solr 4.2](http://solr.pl/en/2013/03/12/apache-lucene-and-solr-4/) and the new DocValues support in Solr.

I want to store the number of clicks in every document in Solr. Is this possible with DocValues now? Can I even update them (without removing the document)?

I have read in the great "Lucene in action" book two years ago that Lucene doesn't support updates. I wonder if DocValues (or something else) change this? Or is it better to store a clicks-per-document-statistic better in a relational database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read through all of the comments on [SOLR-3855](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3855) and found the one one below stating

> Unfortunately doc values are not updateable.

I think a viable option for storing your number of clicks per document would be [ExternalFileField](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Working+with+External+Files+and+Processes) Type. The main limitation is

> External fields are not searchable. They can be used only for function queries or display.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about `ExternalFileField`, looks interesting.